# Wordpress search function not working

Tags: php, wordpress, search

I am fleshing out my first custom Wordpress theme and trying to hook up the search. Now I am following the codex but does not appear to be working correctly. Perhaps I am doing something wrong?

I have added the theme support as this is using the HTML field method.

so here is my search field:

```
            <form role="search" method="get" class="search-form" action="<?php echo home_url( '/' ); ?>">
            <label>
            <input type="search" class="search-field" placeholder="What are you looking for?" value="<?php echo get_search_query() ?>" name="s" title="<?php echo esc_attr_x( 'Search for:', 'label' ) ?>" />
            </label>
            <br />
            <button class="button-search">Find items</button>
            </form>
```

And I have created a search.php with the usual template page bits along the top, created the search page as a page in wordpress, yet when I search I can see the post request in the URL but the page is blank. I am cleary doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you

```
<form role="search" method="get" class="search-form" action="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>">
        <label>
        <input type="text" class="search-field" placeholder="What are you looking for?" value="<?php echo get_search_query() ?>" name="s" id="s" title="<?php echo esc_attr_x( 'Search for:', 'label' ) ?>" />
        </label>
        <br />
    <input type="submit" class="button-search" id="searchsubmit" value="Find items" />
</form>
```